# Pocketsphinx picks random words even with small noise

Tags: android, android-layout, pocketsphinx

I am implementing the pocket sphinx-android-demo-5 pre alpha. In the dictionary I have given few Hindi words.When I run the application,at the start it picks up words from the dictionary randomly.This may be due to background noise around.
I am looking for some help so that I could minimize the background noise as much as possible so that the application works well.

Comment: You need to explain what acoustic model are you using

Comment: I am new to this and my requirements is that....I am supposed to deploy it in a  retail store.So when a person says "sugar one kg", it should pick the voice and then show it on my device. Right now i have not used any acoustic models.I have just defined the words in the dictionary and .gram file.I have no idea how to create a acoustic model,or is it really necessary for one ?? It should just pick any customer who says the product names and eliminate the background noise .